# Iterate Mongoose Properties in Jade

Tags: node.js, mongoose, pug

I'm trying to output a list of properties from a Mongoose object, but I get a lot of Javascript helper functions too. I'm wondering if there's a clean way to just output my Mongoose schema properties.

My Jade display code looks like:

```
h4 Legacy data
ul
- each val, key in d.old
    li= key + ": " + val
```

And my Mongoose schema definition is

```
Entry = new Schema({
    old : {
        submitter : String,
        table     : String,
        wordid    : Number
    }
});
```

But when the page is rendered, there are a bunch of other Javascript properties and functions that get outputted at the same time. e.g.

```
_scope: [object Object]
toObject: function () { return this.get(path); }
wordid: 2035
...
```

Is there an easy way to iterate just through the properties from my schema?
I could use a specified list but I was wondering if there was a nicer way.

Actually, how would I write the specified way? In ruby I know I could do `[ 'wordid', 'submitter' ].each` but is there an equivalent in Jade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're encountering the object's prototype properties.  You can filter them out with `.hasOwnProperty`

```
- each val, key in d.old
- if(d.old.hasOwnProperty(key))
    li= key + ": " + val
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you can also use the method `toJSON` on the document ([mongoose doc of  Document#toJSON](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toJSON)) to get a clean JSON object that can be used in your templates (without worrying about mongoose document's internals and methods). In fact, the `toObject` method you mentioned is similar to `toJSON`, you might wanna [check it out](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject).

For example:

```
doc = EntryModel({old: {submitter: "s", table: "tableS", wordid: "666"}})
console.log(b.toJSON())
// outputs:
{
    "_id": "51fea037434b242816000002",
    "old": {
        "submitter": "s",
        "table": "tableS",
        "wordid": 666
    }
}
// Is a plain JSON object without any other property or method
```